# Problems with FasterCSV (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

I'm writing a program, that creates a csv-File. And I have a problem right at the beginning.
So, my code is

```
  def create_csv
      destfile = Rails.root.join("public", "reports", "statistic_csv#{id}.csv")
      csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |out|
         out << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
      end
   FasterCSV.open(destfile, "w") do |csv|
      csv << csv_string
   end
  end
```

I thought, I will get 4 columns in the output file, smth like this row|of|csv|data. But what I get is "row,of,CSV,data" in one cell A1. How can i solve the Problem? Thanks in advance!
PS. I use ruby 1.8.7 and FasterCSV 1.5.5

Answer (score 2):

You are encoding the CSV string twice. This should work:

```
def create_csv
  destfile = Rails.root.join("public", "reports", "statistic_csv#{id}.csv")
  FasterCSV.open(destfile, "wb") do |csv|
    csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  end
end
```

You can also specify a custom column separator:

```
FasterCSV.open(destfile, "wb", { :col_sep => "|" }) do |csv|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're opening this in Excel.  Excel may not be detecting the file as a CSV file.  Try importing the data into an excel workbook as opposed to opening the file in Excel.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said, and now it looks much better. But now there are some quotation marks in the text "row of CSV data
" "blabla  
"